# Unable to find Nvidia OpenCL SDK

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I am trying to find the Nvidia OpenCL SDK. No luck so fare.

I am starting to give up so I am asking here in case someone can cast some light on the issue.

Comment: Ubuntu install http://askubuntu.com/a/693043/52975

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you have to download and install the CUDA toolkit (which helpfully makes no mention of OpenCL whatsoever) over at https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I had already downloaded and installed CUDA toolkit. I could not find anything about OpenCL when I looked in the installation folder <C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit>.

I took a second look after reading your comment and came over what I was looking for under <C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\OpenCL>.

Comment: That is not the SDK (at least not on my system).  You have to Google the Nvidia OpenCL page as it is not easily accessed from their website.  There you can download each example separately.

Comment: OpenCL samples are available to download individually at https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl. If they won't include them with the CUDA Toolkit, I wish they'd at least allow them all to be downloaded at once.

Answer (score 5):

NVIDIA OpenCL header files are in: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include\CL

Answer (score 2):

just experimented a bit now : linux ...
first - only one platform is good idea, so better to check

```
/etc/OpenCL/vendors
```

and remove intel and amd ...*icd

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/cuda/include make # worked
```

from older notes:

[OCL examples here for your convenience](http://uloz.to/xfwNX2K/nvidia-opencl-examples-cuda-4-2-9-sdk-zip)

```
yum -y install gcc libXmu-devel
```